# Error While using sp-dialog with react project

Tags: spfx

I have a running tsx file that loads a ListView. The project loads fine. I ran the following command

**npm install** **@ microsoft/sp-dialog**

Then in the tsx in added the following import statement.

**import { SPHttpClient } from** '**@ microsoft/sp-http**';

When I use gulp build, I am getting the following error.

**_Error - typescript - node_modules\@microsoft\sp-dialog\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-core-library\lib\deferredCl
ass\DeferredClass.d.ts(25,24): error TS1005: ';' expected._**

I can see the error is pointing to the abstract keyword in the DeferredClass.ts file. How can I fix this?

Comment: run npm install

Comment: have you tried @VindhyachalKumar answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may have just mistyped the commands and code into SO but if not....

You need to remove the space between the @ and microsoft